# phpMyAdmin permissions for config.inc.php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Running an EC2 instance, have installed phpMyAdmin and when I create the config.inc.php file (and move it to the top level directory) and then try to navigate via browser to (mydomain)/phpmyadmin and I get this:

> "Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!"

So, I ran this command:

> chmod 755 config.inc.php

And then when I reload the browser page I get the default chrome "Server Error" page as though there is nothing there at all.

I have repeated the process several times, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that there's an error in the config.inc.php file (IIRC, the test for permissions comes before trying to load the file), so you should first check your webserver error log for hints about what is causing the "Server Error" message.

You can also try loading the config.inc.php file directly (http://example.com/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php or whatever your path is), that might show a better error message.

Answer (score 15):

Here's one solution, though it seems like a hack:

http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2013/02/19/Solve-Wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file%2C-should-not-be-world-writable!-error-on-phpMyAdmin

Same here:

http://www.davinder.in/blog/wrong-permissions-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writable

And this guy says that '705' is actually the permission set you want:

Comment: well, changing it to 705 made something happen. For giggles, I went and changed out all the contents of phpmyadmin/index.php and replaced it with just echo "hello" to see if I could display it. That worked. So it must be something inside of the index.php file that is not working.

Comment: This worked `chmod 0755 config.inc.php` Phew. Thanks. :)

Comment: both links seem to be dead.

Answer (score 10):

If chmod 0644 config.inc.php does not help, perhaps due to a file system issue, you can just disable the check by adding the following to the file:

```
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Needed this for storing PMA on a disk in NTFS format.

Answer (score 4):

change permission of file my.cnf as "sudo chmod 644 -R /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf". it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Change the permission of config.inc.php to 644. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

While i was customizing my settings i changed many places permission through chown and chmod. After that i got this error and solved the problem.

- on my machine ***config.inc.php*** is under /Users/"UserAccountName"/Sites/phpmyadmin/ directory.
- i visited this directory and gave permission "sudo chmod 0755 config.inc.php"

thats it, and i'm done.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot work around the filesystem-related issues, the preferred solution is to avoid this verification, see
https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_CheckConfigurationPermissions

Answer (score 1):

Change the permission of config.inc.php through command as below

sudo chmod -R 777 config.inc.php

Answer (score 1):

If `chmod 0644 config.inc.php` does not help, perhaps due to a filesystem issue, you can just disable the check by adding the following to the file:

`$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Linux and you have `/opt/lampp` then write the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo pkexec chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

Hope it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of file "**/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf**" using the following command. It worked for me on my Mac OS.

```
sudo chmod 644 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the file attribute (under windows) to writeproteced works, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it work

```
sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to

open terminal type

```
opt/lampp/lampp start
```

to start it and then

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

then visit in your browser

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are encounter this error while using xampp (which runs a virtual machine), changing permissions and editing the file **must be done with the virtual machine's terminal**, *not the system terminal*. If you do it with the system terminal (at least on mac os 10.14), the changes will not stick. (that was a couple hours I didn't need...).

Launch terminal from the control panel (see image).

You will need to install an editor.  I used vim.  `apt update`, then `apt install vim`.

Then go to the relevant folder and `sudo chmod 755 config.inc.php`

Then edit the file using `sudo vim config.inc.php`

[image]